# Retrieve data from database using session variable

Tags: php

```
<?php

{
session_start();
include "dbconnect.php";

$email = $_SESSION['email'];
echo $email;
$query = "SELECT uid FROM master WHERE emailid = '$email' ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
while($row)
 {
  $uid=$row[1];

  echo $uid;

   }
```

}
whats wrong in this code.it is giving the email but not able to retrieve uid using session variable email.
please help

Comment: What's stray `{` for?

Answer (score 4):

```
while($row) {
   $uid = $row[1];
   echo $uid;
}
```

should be

```
while($row) {
   $uid=$row['uid'];  
   echo $uid;    
}
```

Try if this code works for you

```
session_start();
include "dbconnect.php";

$email = $_SESSION['email'];
//echo $email;
$query = "SELECT uid FROM master WHERE emailid = '$email' ";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $uid=$row['uid'];
    echo $uid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have `{` at beginning of your code, you should delete that. And second thing, delete `echo $email;` and you should have working code

Comment: What? Why delete `echo`?

Comment: you can use comment section

Answer (score 0):

try $uid=$row[0] instead of $uid=$row[1];
Because $row is an array.Array always starts its counter form 0.
here you have defined $uid=$row[1] which means it will display the result from second row of the result set..But there is no second row there is only one row which is "uid" so try $uid=$row[0] instead of $uid=$row[1];

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
session_start();
include "dbconnect.php";

$email = $_SESSION['email'];

$query = "SELECT uid FROM master WHERE emailid = '".$email."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $uid = $row["uid"];
    echo $uid;
}
else
{
    echo "No record found";
}
?>
```

Comment: thank u anil for the code but it is giving o/p as no record found, while the record is being added

Comment: check database connection then or try to execute the query (echo query in code and execute it in phpmyadmin)